# Option to documentclass{} using a class .cls

Tags: document-classes

I have a problem doing my own class in latex. I want to be able to pass options inside the `\documentclass{my_own_class}` of my `.tex` document, and I thought it would be easy looking at examples on internet, but I cannot figure out how it works.

Here is a very simple example. My `.cls`, called `baz.cls`, is the following:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{baz}

\LoadClass{article}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions \relax

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Then the `.tex` file is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{baz}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to change the font size and/or the option of one or two columns, and maybe more options. But as you can see, or at least it is like that for me, nothing happens when I try with `12pt` and `twocolums`. The result is a `10pt` and `onecolumn` document, which the default options for the article class. If I try `\LoadClass[12pt]{article}`, the result is indeed in `12pt`, but again I cannot change it.

Does anybody know how to proceed ?

Comment: Try to use the `\DeclareOption*` and `\ProcessOptions` before `\LoadClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you load the class which configures some options for itself. Afterwards you tell it that you want it to process some extra options. The point for you is just to swap the order:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{baz}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions \relax
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: I have a question though. That way Latex takes the options of the package before loading the package itself. I thought you should first load the package, then change the options if necessary. I was wrong apparently

Comment: @antoine The command `\PassOptionsToSomething` works another way: It gives the options to the package as soon as this is loaded the first time. To set options later on most packages have distinct commands.